# When and Where should we use hoisting in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript. I'm learning the concept of hoisting in Javascript.
Based on the Javacsript tutorials in [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals) website, I came across this word `hoisting`. According to those tutorials, **variables in JavaScript is that you can refer to a variable declared later, without getting an exception**. But, my question is on what circumstances is it suitable to use hoisting in a  client-side Javascript or why should we use hoisting in Javascript. What are its advantages.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: @gnat Before trying I want to make myself clear with the concept of hoisting and its purposes.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: In this Q&A forum I posted this to understand this topic better and understand its purposes

Comment: @gnat After all the research, if I had understood this topic, why would I have posted this question here, to discuss and understand the concept properly

Comment: There seems to be a fine line here between being new to the topic and asking a question that seems overly broad because you don't know better, and being lazy.  Might I suggest you reference a formal definition of hoisting in your question so people have something to operate off of?

Comment: @Rudra This is not a *discussion* forum. Moreover, you haven't shown *any proof* that you've actually researched this.

Comment: @Doval I have added a few lines based on my research

Comment: @Doval: Proof of research has never been a requirement for asking questions on the Stack Exchange network.  Where did you get that from?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I posted it here to discuss on its usage and I'm asked to show proof of research.

Comment: @RobertHarvey `Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself...` The sharing is a sort of proof that you've at least hit up Google before posting, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but it's not a requirement for asking questions.

Comment: @Rudra: Keep in mind that we're not a *discussion forum.*  We're actually a Q&A site.  Questions asked here should be scoped to be reasonably answerable within the Q&A format.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for setting me straight. Removing my downvote because of that and the edit Rudra made.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Downvote says right on it, "does not show any research effort".  It's not a reason to close, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've never heard the term "hoisting" used.  If you are referring to this usage of hoisting by Ben Cherry: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html, then from what I can gather, he is simply echoing Douglas Crockford from *Javascript: The Good Parts*, and saying that you should **never** *use hoisting*.  His assertion at the end is that all variables should be declared at the top of your function (as Crockford and JSLint suggest).

Or, in the words of Mr. ChristopherBrown, it's not a feature to *use*, per-say, but simply a quirk related to how the browser interprets Javascript.

So, in short: **never** and **nowhere**.

Comment: Then, why is this concept included and what is this feature about?

Comment: @Rudra: The subtopic "Declarations, Names, and Hoisting" in the article David linked seems to cover this pretty well.  Which part is unclear?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I just want to know, where and when they use this. David says it is used never and nowhere, but why is it shown as a feature

Comment: Just because something is a feature doesn't mean it's a good idea.  There are many reasons why "features" fall out of favor.  Even your appendix serves no apparently useful purpose, even though it probably did in the cave man days.

Comment: HOisting is a term from compiler theory, especially optimisation. It's been around for at least 20 years, but made popular by this peculiarity of Javascript. If it wasn't called a feature, it would probably be a bug.

Answer (score 17):

Hoisting describes a feature of how Javascript is interpreted by the browser, and isn't so much a feature to be used.

When interpreting Javascript, browsers scope function-level variables at the beginning of the function.  Example:

```
function AddTwoAndTwo() {
    var two = 2;
    var result = two + two;
    return result;
}
```

In the posted code, both variables "two" and "result" exist at the start of function scope (obviously, as they're declared there.)  However, because the browsers are "hoisting" the variables, the following becomes legal Javascript code.

```
function AddTwoAndTwo() {
    result = 5;
    alert(result);
    var two = 2;
    var result = two + two;
    return result;
}
```

The net effect here is that you have variables in use before you declare them, and that can cause confusion, especially with global-scope variables. Example:

```
var result = 6;

function AddTwoAndTwo() {
    alert(result);  // should this be 6 or undefined?
    var two = 2;
    var result = two + two;
    return result;
}
```

To avoid confusion, declare your variables at the top of a function.

Comment: +1: this is how I would answer. It's not a feature to use or not use, it's just a property of the environment to take into account.

Answer (score 3):

**Why?**

JavaScript doesn't have *Block Scope*, that should explain why things should *hoist* to the top.

**Is it useful?**

If you prefer this:

```
var someVariable = someVariable || {};
```

Instead of this:

```
if ( "undefined" !== typeof someVariable ) {
    someVariable = someVariable;
} else {
    someVariable = {};
}
```

Then it is useful. Even if you don't notice it!

**Clearification**

First example will translate to something like this:

```
var someVariable = someVariableValue;

if ( "undefined" !== typeof someVariable ) {
    var someVariableValue = someVariable;
} else {
    var someVariableValue = {};
}
```